# What is the difference between docker-image and registry-image in concourse?

Tags: docker, concourse, concourse-resource-types

In Concourse, under the `resources` section, i sometimes encounter the type `registry-image` and sometimes the type `docker-image`.

```
resources:

  - name: some-image   
    type: registry-image      
    source:                   
      repository: 1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/some-image
      tag: 2.4.5              

  - name: other-image
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: 1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/other-image
      tag: latest
```

They look similar but what is exactly the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While googling i found the answer on the [github page of registry-image](https://github.com/concourse/registry-image-resource#comparison-to-docker-image-resource)

> This resource is intended as a replacement for the Docker Image
> resource. Here are the key differences:
>
> - This resource is implemented in pure Go and does not use the Docker daemon or CLI. This makes it safer (no need for privileged: true),
>   more efficient, and less error-prone (now that we're using Go APIs and
>   not parsing docker CLI output).
> - This resource has stronger test coverage.
> - This resource does not and will never support building - only registry image pushing/pulling. Building should instead be done with
>   something like the oci-build task (or anything that can produce OCI
>   image tarballs).
> - A goal of this resource is to stay as focused and simple as possible. The Docker Image resource grew way too large and
>   complicated. There are simply too many ways to build and publish
>   Docker images. It will be easier to support many smaller resources +
>   tasks rather than one huge interface.